# Is it possible to determine if a Street View is user submitted using the Google Maps JavaScript API?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

Here is an example of a [user submitted Street View](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Buenos+Aires,+Autonomous+City+of+Buenos+Aires,+Argentina/@-34.6182608,-58.3646,3a,75y,233.63h,90t/data=!3m8!1e1!3m6!1s-Xy8BHdeY1iM%2FU8qFqapqFdI%2FAAAAAAAAE6M%2FUAzT3NQAV3UGknoGofJxn67cxZS8mZqeg!2e4!3e11!6s%2F%2Flh6.googleusercontent.com%2F-Xy8BHdeY1iM%2FU8qFqapqFdI%2FAAAAAAAAE6M%2FUAzT3NQAV3UGknoGofJxn67cxZS8mZqeg%2Fw207-h100-n-k-no%2F!7i6656!8i3208!4m5!3m4!1s0x95bcca3b4ef90cbd:0xa0b3812e88e88e87!8m2!3d-34.6036844!4d-58.3815591!6m1!1e1) vs a [Google created view](https://www.google.com/maps/@-34.6080742,-58.371722,3a,75y,270.69h,85.22t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sqoY8zEaEpt1gPRisqjunpA!2e0!7i13312!8i6656!6m1!1e1).

Given a lat/lng, is it possible to determine whether the Street View is user submitted?

As a heuristic, I can check `pano.getLinks().length === 0`, but it's hacky at best.

EDIT: Looks like a `StreetViewPanorama` object has a `streetViewDataProviders` property which could be checked for the data source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it can be done using the Google Maps JavaScript API but the closest to use is the copyright property from `google.maps.StreetViewPanoramaData`

> [StreetViewPanoramaData](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#StreetViewPanoramaData)
>
> - The representation of a panorama returned from the provider defined using `registerPanoProvider`.

A `StreetViewPanoramaData` is an object of the following form:

```
{
copyright: string,
location: {
description: string,
latLng: google.maps.LatLng,
pano: string
},
tiles: {
tileSize: google.maps.Size,
worldSize: google.maps.Size,
heading: number,
getTileUrl: Function
},
links: [
description: string,
heading: number,
pano: string,
roadColor: string,
roadOpacity: number
]
}
```

**copyright** - Specifies the copyright text for this panorama.

Hope it helps!